# change styles dynamically with react memo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am learning to use react memo, I am applying it to a simple task application, my problem is that I do not know how to make the styles of the items in the list work well.

[image: Image from Gyazo]

As you can see when completing a task, I don't know how to update the styles of the other items in the list so that it is one in white and one in black.

I tried many things but nothing worked :(

TaskItem.jsx

```
import React, { memo } from 'react'
import styled from "styled-components"
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import store from "../../redux/store";

//STYLES

const DIV = styled.div`

    max-height: ${
        props => !useSelector((state)=> state.toggleDoneTasks.show) && props.done ? "0px" : "50px"
    };

    opacity: ${
        props => !useSelector((state)=> state.toggleDoneTasks.show) && props.done ? "0": "1"
    };

    padding: ${
        props => !useSelector((state)=> state.toggleDoneTasks.show) && props.done ? "0px":"12px 15px"
    };

    overflow: hidden;
    transition: opacity 0.5s, max-height 0.5s, padding 0.5s;
`;

const TR = styled.tr`
    background-color: ${
        (props) => {

            //show completed and not completed tasks
            if(useSelector((state)=> state.toggleDoneTasks.show)){
                return props.index % 2 === 0 ? '#f3f3f3': 'none'
            }

            const tasksNotDone = props.tasks.filter((task) => !task.done)
            const index = tasksNotDone.findIndex(t => t.id === props.task.id)
            return index % 2 === 0 ? '#f3f3f3': 'none'

        }
    };

    /* 
    &:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC};
    &:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}; 
    */

    border-bottom: ${
        props => !useSelector((state)=> state.toggleDoneTasks.show) && props.task.done ? "none": "1px solid #dddddd"
    };;

    transition: visibility 0.5s;

    cursor: pointer;
    &:hover{
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #009879;
    }
`;


function TaskRow({ task, toggleDoneTask, index, tasks }) {

    return (
        
        <TR task={task} tasks={tasks} index={index}>
            <td>
                <DIV done={task.done}>
                    {console.log('render', task)}
                    {task.title}
                </DIV>
            </td>
            <td>
                <DIV done={task.done}>
                    {task.description}
                </DIV>
            </td>
            <td>
                <DIV  done={task.done}>
                    <input type="checkbox"
                        checked={task.done}
                        onChange={toggleDoneTask}
                        style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}
                    />
                </DIV>
            </td>
        </TR>
    )
}


export default memo(TaskRow, (prev, next) => {
    // store.getState().toggleDoneTasks.show

    //COMPARE TASK OBJECT
    const prevTaskKeys = Object.keys(prev.task);
    const nextTaskKeys = Object.keys(next.task);

    const sameLength = prevTaskKeys.length === nextTaskKeys.length;
    const sameEntries = prevTaskKeys.every(key => {
        return nextTaskKeys.includes(key) && prev.task[key] === next.task[key];
    });

    return sameLength && sameEntries;
})
```

Tasks.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import TaskItem from "./TaskItem";

function saveLocalStorage(tasks) {
  localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(tasks));
}

function TasksReducer(taskItems, { type, task }) {
  switch (type) {
    case "UPDATE_TAKS": {
      let taskItemsCopy = [...taskItems].map((task) => ({ ...task }));
      let newItems = taskItemsCopy.map((t) => {
        if (t.id === task.id) {
          t.done = !t.done;
        }
        return t;
      });
      saveLocalStorage(newItems);
      return newItems;
    }

    case "ADD_TASK": {
      const newItems = [...taskItems, task];
      saveLocalStorage(newItems);
      return newItems;
    }

    default:
      window.alert("INVALID ACTION");
      break;
  }
}

const initialState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks")) || [];

//STYLES

const styleTable = {
  borderCollapse: "collapse",
  margin: "25px 0",
  fontSize: "0.9em",
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  minWidth: "400px",
  boxShadow: "0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)"
};

const styleTr = {
  backgroundColor: "#009879",
  color: "#ffffff",
  textAlign: "left"
};

const styleTh = {
  padding: "12px 15px"
};

function Tasks({ newTask, show }) {
  const [taskItems, dispatch] = useReducer(TasksReducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!newTask) return;
    newTaskHandler({ id: taskItems.length + 1, ...newTask });
  }, [newTask]);

  const newTaskHandler = (task) => {
    dispatch({ type: "ADD_TASK", task });
  };

  const toggleDoneTask = (task) => {
    dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_TAKS", task });
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>learning react </h1>
      <table style={styleTable}>
        <thead>
          <tr style={styleTr}>
            <th style={styleTh}>Title</th>
            <th style={styleTh}>Description</th>
            <th style={styleTh}>Done</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {taskItems.map(
            (task, i) =>
              (show || !task.done) && (
                <TaskItem
                  tasks={taskItems}
                  index={i}
                  task={task}
                  key={task.id}
                  show={show}
                  toggleDoneTask={() => toggleDoneTask(task)}
                />
              )
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default Tasks;
```

If you need the complete code:
[image: Edit inspiring-sea-hp9kt]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### About Memo and your app

`Memo` could be useful when you don't expect your component to change often. It comes with a cost that does these evaluations to verify if it should rerender.

In your case you would have a lot of rerenders because several components would need to be rerender to fit the correct background which is a downside to use `Memo`.

Besides, you would see these bugs, since other components won't rerender given their props won't change.

I would suggest to remove memo for this case.

#### About your show state

You see the accordion effect that you have right? You wouldn't see that effect if the component did unmount. That means the component never unmounts. You are using 2 `show` states, one state created at root at your App and another state that comes from your reducer.

Your button only flips the reducer `show` state. But to render `TaskItem` you use the stale show state created, that is always true. If you were using the redux state there wouldn't be any effect at all:

```
// show is always true unless you pass state from your reducer like:
// const show = useSelector((state) => state.toggleDoneTasks.show);
(show || !task.done) && (
                <TaskItem
                  tasks={taskItems}
                  index={i}
                  task={task}
                  key={task.id}
                  show={show}
                  toggleDoneTask={() => toggleDoneTask(task)}
                />
              )
```

so you should remove your React show state:

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('show')) || true)
```

Or remove your reducer, but for learning purposes you can keep the reducer.

Sandbox without the extra state, and no effects:
[image: sandbox]

#### About the accordion effect

Given that you won't have anymore the accordion effect. For you to solve that you can either:

- pick up a react animation library that handles transition effects on component mounting and unmounting of your preference;
- render all Tasks (without `(show || !task.done)` condition). And keep track at each Task how many tasks are `done` until that given Task. With that you can do some logic like:

```
    const indexToPass = show ? index : index - doneTasksBefore 

   ...

  <TR task={task} tasks={tasks} index={indexToPass}>
```

Comment: Thanks, now I have it clearer, but I have one last question, is there a way to optimize a very large list? avoiding re-rendering the list when an element changes

Comment: This may get complex, and I would like also to have a clear answer for that! What I can add is when you have complex states you would handle it more likely with `redux` (just like you were doing with show) and there's a library called `reselect` that allows to memoize selectors  which I think you will enjoy, cheers! https://www.npmjs.com/package/reselect